# Remove data from NSKeyedArchvier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, archive, nskeyedarchiver

I am storing data with NSKeyedArchiver.  When a user logs out of my app, I would like to clear all the data that I have stored.  How can I go about doing that?  It doesn't appear that `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:]` removes the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSKeyedArchiver & NSKeyedUnarchiver` only encode and decode your objects so they can be stored and retreived. If you are storing the data in a file, just delete the file (use `NSFileManager`). If you are storing data in other places (eg `NSUserDefaults`, a database, etc) then you need to delete the data as appropriate for the store.